# How to filter chinese (ONLY chinese)

Tags: python

I want to convert some text that include some punctuation and full-width symbols to pure chinese text.

```
maybe_re = re.compile("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") #TODO
print "".join(maybe_re.findall("你好,这只是一些中文文本.．，．，全角"))

# I want out
你好这只是一些中文文本全角
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any good way to separate Chinese characters from other letters, but you can distinguish letters from other characters. Using regexes, you can use `r"\w"` (compiled with the `re.UNICODE` flag if you're on Python 2). That will include numbers as well as letters, but not punctuation.

`unicodedata.category(c)` will tell you what type of character c is. Your Chinese letters are "Lo" (letter without case), while the punctuation is "Po".

Comment: @Dreampuf: regular expressions? Not as far as I know. But you can use `''.join(c for c in s if unicodedata.category(c).startswith('L'))`

Answer (score 4):

The Zhon library provides you with a list of Chinese punctuation marks: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zhon

```
str = re.sub('[%s]' % zhon.unicode.PUNCTUATION, "", "你好,这只是一些中文文本.．，．，全角")
```

This does *almost* what you want. Not exactly, because the sentence you provide contains some very non-standard punctuation marks, such as "．". Anyway, I think Zhon might be useful to others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but for future reference: the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, unlike the re module, supports [Unicode regex](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/) patterns for [scripts](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex#unicode-codepoint-properties-including-scripts-and-blocks).

It is sufficient for the question's purpose to match only Han ideographs. `\p{script=Han}` would match any Han ideograph. `\p{isHan}`, `\p{sc=Han}` and `\p{Han}` are abbreviated forms of the pattern.

```py
import regex as re
s = "你好,这只是一些中文文本.．，．，全角"
print("".join(re.findall(r'\p{Han}', s)))
# 你好这只是一些中文文本全角
```